# Why is the color in grease pencil different from what i set?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image: Color values differ]

I was opening a grease pencil animation and it is much brighter than what it is supposed to be in the final rendered result. The color on top in the box next to eye, this blue is the actual color I saved two and a halve years ago. And today it is set to the color you see in the fill box. It is animated to become a cyan color. Why is this the case? I guess that colors couldn't be safed properly from a 2.8 build i guess. But now i have to redo all of my animations. I opened it in 2.93 and 3.3.1 and both are the same.

Comment: Without being able to reproduce this right now, I can only say one thing: that's unfortunately not unlikely for software, with changing features and further development it is highly possible that old files don't work exactly like they did before and you might have to redo things. And this is definitely not limited to Blender.

Comment: could you delete the keyframe that changes the colour to cyan? the fact that the correct blue shows up as the material icon makes me think that at some point in the animation it is that colour.

Comment: @pevinkinel It was that color when i rendered it years ago. But it has a different color value, even Hex code. And it's every color. And it's not limited to this project. All of the projects from the 2.83 build have the wrong colors now. As if the location of the save data got changed.

Comment: right, I see. Then Gordon's comment is right, sorry. Apart from using the same build you used back then, the only thing I can think of is colour picking each material icon and reassigning that to each base colour, but that might not be doable if you have hundred of them